# Ambiance theme git repository

Tags: themes, repository, git, ambiance

Does the default theme for Ubuntu (*Ambiance*) have an official git repository?

I want to modify it adding my tweaks, and it already has a git repository I choose to take it as start repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Ambiance* theme is maintained in the [light-themes](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/light-themes) package.
You can find the source of the package in [launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-art-pkg/ubuntu-themes/trunk/files).

**Note**: it's not a git repo but a bzr repo; you can branch the project this way:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr
bzr branch lp:ubuntu-themes
```

Alternatively a quick way to get the source is:

```
apt-get source light-themes
```

---

**Update:** How to convert the ubuntu-themes bzr repo into git

There's probably several ways to do this, but here is mine. I often use [git-lp](https://github.com/zyga/git-lp) to work with bzr branch on launchpad while keeping the power of git locally. Just follow the [README](https://github.com/zyga/git-lp/blob/master/README.md) to install it.

Once installed, the following commands will create a working git repo:

```
$ git lp init --fetch  lp:ubuntu-themes
$ cd ubuntu-themes
$ git lp branch my_dev
```

Then all you have to do is to push to your github repo (See [Pushing to a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote))

I did the operation myself, here's my [git repo](https://github.com/yphus/ubuntu-themes) containing ubuntu-themes.

Comment: you can downolad the source code without installing bzr, either with a browser / wget or apt-get

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: You're right, bzr is not mandatory. I've updated my answer. Thx

Comment: I guess bzr repositories can be converted in git ones, right? I just copied the files from `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance` for now. I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: You'ld get an upvote from me if you added a small script to get source, clobber files in the current git tracked folder, commit, and push - assuming saved credentials.  This way the OP could take your data and throw it in a cron job to make a github repo as a jumping off point.

Comment: @hbdgaf: I've updated my answer with a way to get a git repo at the end.

Comment: And there are some points... ;)

Comment: @SylvainPineau There are some recent changes in the Ambiance theme. Where can I see them in the bzr of git repositories...?